# PHP Upgrade Broken Member confirmations

Tags: civimail

Great timing as our rugby club is days away from the new season! After upgrading PHP and Civi the 'renew member' funcion seems to stall. It opens the details required but wont use the template confirmation we created. Just spins the triangle and one has to log out to cancel the operation.
Any one else had the same experience?
Cheers
Ian

Comment: Welcome to SE!  What are your current and previous versions of both Civi and PHP?  Is there anything in the Civi log file?  Have you tried clearing the cache?